# Excel VBA - DLL Not found unless placed on C:

Tags: excel, vba, dll, operating-system

I have two DLLs that contain functions that I want to call from VBA, and normally these DLLs are held in a network location.  They both have functions declared in the exact same way:

```
Declare Function buildMatrix Lib "T:\_____Dllv2.dll" (Variables) As Double
Declare Function DoSomethingElse Lib "T:\_____Dllv1.dll" (Variables) As Double
```

Dllv1 works perfectly fine. Dllv2 throws a "File Not Found" error.

When I put Dllv2 onto my C:/ through, it works perfectly fine!   I know it's not the security issue with network directory though, because it's the same directory as Dllv1 which works fine!

Any thoughts...  Driving me nuts..

Thanks